# How to create a pdf from html, without any page break?

Tags: html, css, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

I am creating a pdf from HTML using ITextRenderer in java. I want the pdf document to have only a single page. I tried using the below configs in the CSS file

```
* {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
@page {
    size: 1600px 100vh;
}
```

But both didn't seem to have any effect.
Also, my content is dynamic so I can't know the height in advance.
I am not able to find any working solution.
Can you please let me know how to achieve this?

Thanks